# Find old tweets using Python tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Python 3.9.5

tweepy == 4.10.0

I am trying to get old tweets using tweepy but it does not work well (shows 0 result).
Here's what I tried.

```
BEARER_TOKEN = "My Token"

DATE_STA = "2020-01-01T00:00:01Z"
DATE_END = "2020-06-01T23:59:59Z"

client = tweepy.Client(BEARER_TOKEN, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
user = client.get_user(username="hellopolicy")
res = client.get_users_tweets(
    user.data.id,
    end_time     = DATE_END,
    start_time   = DATE_STA,
    max_results  = 100,
    tweet_fields = ["text", "created_at", "conversation_id", "public_metrics"]
)

print(res)
# Response(data=None, includes={}, errors=[], meta={'result_count': 0})
```

But if I search it manually from the web with a query (from:hellopolicy since:2020-01-01 until:2020-06-01), I can see many tweets during that period.

This behavior depends on target IDs. Most of them showed all results correctly but the others (1-2 out of 10) showed only a couple of weeks or nothing. Numbers of tweets in the IDs were not the matter.

Why This happens and how can I get all the tweets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `get_users_tweets()` documentation ([see here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.get_users_tweets)):

> Only the 3200 most recent Tweets are available.

So you can not access the user's tweets in this interval if he sent 3 200 tweets since then.

Comment: Yep. I was confused. I though 'up to 3,200 tweets during the given period' but actually it was 'since today'.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have any results returned due to the limited range of dates that you may scrape with the [standard API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/overview#:%7E:text=The%20Twitter%20Search%20API%20searches,in%20the%20past%207%20days.&text=Query%20abilities%3A%20Limited%20operators%20for,functionality%20in%20the%20Twitter%20UI.). As quoted:

> The Twitter Search API searches against a sampling of recent Tweets published in the past 7 days.

I have a script that may be useful for scraping older tweets on my [GitHub](https://github.com/ahjimomo/old_twitter_scraping) to circumvent this issue. Hope it helps.